# How to fill value in text field with in iframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I am writing cucumber feature and I need to fill value in text field within iframe. I have tried with

```
find("#user_email").set "malicious_value"
```

but couldn't get success. I have selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ruby code with selenium to switch in iframe. you can do it by:

```
#Move into iframe
page.driver.browser.switch_to.frame "name or id of frame"

#Move to default content or outsite frame
page.driver.browser.switch_to.default_content
```

Comment: There is some good link for iframe with selenium are [Iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909149/how-can-i-switch-between-two-frames-with-capybara) and [Iframe1](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do any thing inside the `frame`. First you have to go inside the frame.

**Code to enter the frame:**

```
  //Assume driver is initiated properly some where.
  driver.switchTo.frame(FrameName);

(Or)  
  driver.switchTo.frame(FrameIndexValue);  

(Or)  
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(LocatorValue));  
  driver.switchTo.frame(element);
```

After finishing your action inside the frame. You have to come out to frame by using

**code to leave the frame:**

```
  driver.switchTo.defaultContent();
```

If you are dealing with the `iframe` then the defaultContent() will take you to the main page above all the iframes, but if you deal with the `frame` this method will take you to the first frame of the page.

For more information on [frame handling](http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.ca/2012/04/frames-and-webdriver.html).

Comment: I am getting error when I have used it: NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `switchTo' for #<Capybara::Selenium::Driver:0xb206aec>.
I need a code for ruby selenium

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake. Use this link [frame handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909149/how-can-i-switch-between-two-frames-with-capybara). It may help you. If its not work let me know.