# handling iframe with capybara ruby

Tags: ruby, capybara

Below is the html code ..

```
<iframe id="I0_1366100881331" frameborder="0" width="100%">
<div class="ZRa">
<span id="button" class="hAa Qo Bg" tabindex="0" role="button" title="" aria-      label="Click here to publicly +1 this." aria-pressed="false">
</div>
</iframe>
```

In the above scenario, I want to switch into the IFRAME (iframe id="I0_1366100881331") to perform some actions on the SPAN present in that IFRAME. I have tried with most of the cases but no result :(... any one please help.

I want the solution for cucumber using capybara ruby only..

Note: I tried with following code but no result.

page.driver.browser.switch_to.frame "I0_1366100881331"

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909149/how-can-i-switch-between-two-frames-with-capybara

Answer (score 37):

```
within_frame(find('<css rule>')) do
  <code for dealing with iframe entries>
end
```

Comment: This worked well for me, and since it uses 'find' Capybara will wait for the frame to appear on the page if necessary.

Answer (score 14):

I think you can try to use method:

```
within_frame 'id' do
  <code for dealing with iframe entries>
end
```

Comment: 'id' is not static one. It is changing every time (page refresh), then how we can handle the iframe by using 'id'. Can you please suggest?

Comment: Old post, but you must have been able to get the ID of the frame somehow given the sample code you posted above.

Answer (score -1):

Can have this code:

```
withinframe((:xpath,"//div")) do
#code
end
```