# Capybara::ElementNotFound - How to click on specific button with id using Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara

Trying to access this button on `root url`:

[image]

here is `html`

[image]

with this test:

```
feature "New comment button" do
  scenario "User can add new comment on root page", :js => true do
    visit root_path
    id = 152
    click_button("#button_#{id}")
    within("#comment_row_#{id}") do
        fill_in('content', :with => 'this is a comment')
        click_button('create comment')
        page.must_have_flash_message('Successfully created')
    end
  end
```

and geting this:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find button "#button_152"
```

How to get this element using `id` ?

I am using `selenium-web-driver`

EDIT

**WHAT I TRIED**

```
# page.driver.browser.switch_to.frame 'top-frame' # Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchFrameError: Unable to locate frame: top-frame
# page.find('#button_152').click          # not working
# click_button("#button_152")             # not working
# first(:xpath, '//button[@id="button_152"]').click
```

2.This is an overview of frames :

[image]

3. all iframes are just `google chrome addons`

[image]

4.[link to full html](https://gist.github.com/mrohon/8568598)

Comment: It's possible that the element is in a frame or iframe. There may also be an issue where the button is not loading until after Selenium tests for it.

Comment: Added `html` code. Not sure what do you mean with iframe. Button loads ok, when I run selenium I visually see how it opens the page and there is a button.

Comment: The table may be contained within an iframe or frame.  Selenium only sees content in the current frame.  It starts out at the top of the dom.  If there is an iframe or frame in the code, that contains your button element, then you'll need to do something like driver.Switch().Frame(frameID); before you can access the button element.

Comment: Interesting.Updated my question for `frames`. Know nothing about frames and selenium - How does it work? What kind of good online resources would you recommend to read ?

Comment: Would it be possible to post more HTML?  Does the button ID change each time it is run?

Comment: yes, see the update and link to full html - gist

Comment: I think maybe the issue is the #.  From what I'm seeing, click_button (and other Capybara parameters) are expected to be IDs, so using `click_button("button_#{id}")` may fix your issue.

Comment: already tied that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about switching windows and frames here: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#moving-between-windows-and-frames

Ruby specific bindings here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings

Capybara handling iframes:  [handling iframe with capybara ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034224/handling-iframe-with-capybara-ruby)

As for your problem, here's an example you can edit:

```
within_frame 'evernoteFilingTools' do
  click_button("#button_#{id}")
  #button_#{id} # not working 
  #page.find("#button_#{id}",:visible => true).click # does not work as well
  within("#comment_row_#{id}") do
    fill_in('content', :with => 'this is a comment')
    click_button('create comment')
    page.must_have_flash_message('Successfully created')
  end
end
```

You should replace evernoteFilingTools with the iframe ID that contains the content you want to manipulate

Comment: thanks for links, but this answer does not work. All my iframes are supposed to be google chrome addons.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it can be thrown off by invalid markup. This HTML has a `div` (`<div class="icons">`) inside a table, which is not valid. Try running the markup through a validator such as http://validator.w3.org/ and fix any errors it reports. That might fix your Capybara problem as well.