# Ruby capybara Unable to find link or button "search"

Tags: ruby, capybara

I have the problem with a simple script:

```
Given(/^I am on the main home page$/) do
  visit 'xxx.se'
end
When(/^I search for "(.*?)"$/) do
|search_term|
  fill_in 'q', :with => search_term
  click_on 'search'
end
Then(/^videos of large rodents are returned$/) do

  expect(page).to have_content 'Samsung'
```

but I got an error

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find link or button "search"
./features/step_definitions/steps.rb:7:in `/^I search for "(.*?)"$/'
```

link to inspect element here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgHq8.jpg

Comment: Looks like the page elements are in a `iframe`.  This SO answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034224/handling-iframe-with-capybara-ruby

Comment: Your image doesn't show what the actual text in the button is - is it maybe 'Search'  (case matters when trying to click on a button by the text it is showing)

Comment: thanks but I do no have frame here?

Answer (score 0):

try `find("button[aria-label='Search']")` it probably can help 
you can read about clicks here 
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions

Answer (score 0):

As `click on` does not support css selectors you can use `find` instead

`find(:css,  "button.search-form-button").click`