# Cabybara find element based on element name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

Hi i am trying to select input field and add value into stripe's iframe, based on element name.
this won't work

```
page.find(:name, 'exp-date')
```

i was able to select root div with id selector, but i can't select input field which is child node somewhere in root div

```
  find(:id, "root")
```

Any idea how to target those  fields

Comment: Capybara doesn't provide a `:name`  selector so it's not really surprising that doesn't work (and unless you're running a pretty old version of Capybara it should have output a warning about an unknown selector) . Please add the methods you've tried and the exact error messages they produce to the question - adding the relevant portion of HTML you're trying to interact with would also be helpful.

Comment: Post the html of the frame you're trying to interact with

Comment: i think that iframe content is disabled by phantom js trying to add some flag like --web-security=no

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the capybara `find_field` method to find field inputs.  Checkout the docs here:
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Finders#find_field-instance_method

Would look something like: `find_field('attributes[form_field_attribute_you_need]')`

Comment: hey buddy tried this before find_field('name[cvc]')

Comment: Have you tried the within_frame method?  Checkout this stack post similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034224/handling-iframe-with-capybara-ruby

Comment: yeah tried with within_frame, googled whole day i was able to select root div in iframe, but cannot select input node with cvc card name or card number

Comment: Perhaps the element inside the iframe hasn't been loaded?  What are you using with capy?  Any js headless browser etc.

Comment: i have poltergeist and selenium driver

Comment: @vladimirProp unless the input looks like   `<input name="name[cvc]" ... >` - you're use of `find_field` is wrong.  `find_field` takes the name, id, or label text of the input to find, so if your input is . `<input name="cvc" ... >`, as I think you're implying, it would just be `find_field('cvc')`

Comment: yeah it seems this element cvc isn't visible in iframe for some reason

Comment: i think that iframe content is disabled by phantom js trying to add some flag like --web-security=no

Comment: problem was in outdated version of capybara try to update and iframe will be visible

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS selector here:

```
find('input[name="exp-date"]', match: :first).set('my value')
```

Comment: i got error The browser raised a syntax error while trying to evaluate css selector "//input[@name=\"cvc\"]"

Comment: The quoting is important `'input[@name="exp-date"]'`. It should single quotes containing double quotes just as I wrote it

Comment: yes this is my code     find('//input[@name="cvc"]', match: :first).set('1234')

Comment: I updated the code that should work. It is just a CSS selector, not XPath, my mistake.

Comment: same sintax error i will try to escape find('input[@name=\"cvc\"]', match: :first).set('12345')

Comment: not sure why slashes are added "input[@name=\"cvc\"]

Comment: @vladimirProp The slashes are added because to show the inner "s are inside the outer "s - Also, it should be  `input[name="cvc"]` -- @ is only used to select attributes in XPath expressions (not CSS)

Comment: i think that iframe content is disabled by phantom js trying to add some flag like --web-security=no

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works with an iframe, but you should be able to use:

```
within('#target_form_id') do #or another selector
  fill_in 'field_name_or_id', with: 'value'
  fill_in 'another_field', with: 'another_value'
end
```

Comment: yeah tried that definitely not working with iframe and method within_frame

Comment: and you're sure you have an iframe to navigate to when you try? Have you tried printing out the iframe element to see if it's available?

Comment: yeah i was able to select node with root id in it

Comment: but I mean the contents of it? isn't it loaded through stripe checkout.js or something?

Comment: not sure how to check content, tried to echo something with puts

Comment: you can do `root_element_object.children.each do |c| puts c.name if c.children.count > 0 c.children.each do |c2| puts c2.name #.... end end end` you can nest the loops to further dig, or create a function that digs through and then call it recursively whenever there's .children.count > 0

Comment: You can just do `puts page.html` when inside the iframe to see the iframes source.

Comment: yeah it seems this element cvc isn't visible in iframe for some reason

Comment: i think that iframe content is disabled by phantom js trying to add some flag like --web-security=no