# PhantomJs iframe not loading

Tags: iframe, phantomjs, capybara

Hello i am using capybara test, to test app. However iframe isn't displayed with automated testing. Trying to test stripe elements, which are stored in iframe. I suspect it's something related with phanotmjs settings. Tried to add web-security option to conf

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  options = {
      :timeout => DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME,
      :debug => false,
      :phantomjs_options => ['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--ssl-protocol=any', '--disk-cache=false', '--load-images=no', '--web-security=false' ],
      :inspector => false,
      :js_errors => false
  }
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
end
```

anyone with some idea how to solve this, maybe with similar problem

Comment: What is the actual content of the iframe?

Comment: It's stripe iframe version 3, we had discussion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329095/cabybara-find-element-based-on-element-name that was the issue

Comment: Yes, and you still haven’t posted the actual HTML contents of the frame so we can help you.  Add the result of `page.html` being run inside `within_frame`. You may need to sleep a few seconds before running it to make sure the frame has fully loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in outdated version of capybara, try to update it, and this issue will gone, also update phantomJS